# How to connect couchbase db located in cluster from localhost using port forwarding in my app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, networking, couchbase

I need your help. So, we have couchbase cluster on AWS. I need to connect this db from my web application to test it on my local machine. Our app is developed using Golang. I need to debug my app on my local. I am using Couchbase GoSDK to connect to couchbase DB but I cant connect to localhost:8091 from project even I did port forwarding. Here is the logs of couchbase GOSDK.

```
GOCB 12:48:01.777192 cluster.go:259: SDK Version: gocbcore/v10.0.6
GOCB 12:48:01.777444 cluster.go:259: Creating new agent group: &{AgentConfig:{BucketName: UserAgent:gocb/v2.3.5 SeedConfig:{HTTPAddrs:[localhost:8091] MemdAddrs:[localhost:11210]} SecurityConfig:{UseTLS:false TLSRootCAProvider:0x169f340 NoTLSSeedNode:false Auth:0xc000332100 AuthMechanisms:[]} CompressionConfig:{Enabled:false DisableDecompression:false MinSize:0 MinRatio:0} ConfigPollerConfig:{HTTPRedialPeriod:0s HTTPRetryDelay:0s HTTPMaxWait:0s CccpMaxWait:0s CccpPollPeriod:0s} IoConfig:{NetworkType: UseMutationTokens:true UseDurations:true UseOutOfOrderResponses:true DisableXErrorHello:false DisableJSONHello:false DisableSyncReplicationHello:false EnablePITRHello:false UseCollections:true} KVConfig:{ConnectTimeout:10s ServerWaitBackoff:0s PoolSize:0 MaxQueueSize:0} HTTPConfig:{MaxIdleConns:0 MaxIdleConnsPerHost:0 IdleConnectionTimeout:0s} DefaultRetryStrategy:0xc0007de080 CircuitBreakerConfig:{Enabled:true VolumeThreshold:0 ErrorThresholdPercentage:0 SleepWindow:0s RollingWindow:0s CompletionCallback:<nil> CanaryTimeout:0s} OrphanReporterConfig:{Enabled:true ReportInterval:0s SampleSize:0} TracerConfig:{Tracer:0xc0007de0a0 NoRootTraceSpans:true} MeterConfig:{Meter:<nil>}}}
GOCB 12:48:01.777467 agentgroup.go:30: SDK Version: gocbcore/v10.0.6
GOCB 12:48:01.777507 agentgroup.go:30: Creating new agent: &{BucketName: UserAgent:gocb/v2.3.5 SeedConfig:{HTTPAddrs:[localhost:8091] MemdAddrs:[localhost:11210]} SecurityConfig:{UseTLS:false TLSRootCAProvider:0x169f340 NoTLSSeedNode:false Auth:0xc000332100 AuthMechanisms:[]} CompressionConfig:{Enabled:false DisableDecompression:false MinSize:0 MinRatio:0} ConfigPollerConfig:{HTTPRedialPeriod:0s HTTPRetryDelay:0s HTTPMaxWait:0s CccpMaxWait:0s CccpPollPeriod:0s} IoConfig:{NetworkType: UseMutationTokens:true UseDurations:true UseOutOfOrderResponses:true DisableXErrorHello:false DisableJSONHello:false DisableSyncReplicationHello:false EnablePITRHello:false UseCollections:true} KVConfig:{ConnectTimeout:10s ServerWaitBackoff:0s PoolSize:0 MaxQueueSize:0} HTTPConfig:{MaxIdleConns:0 MaxIdleConnsPerHost:0 IdleConnectionTimeout:0s} DefaultRetryStrategy:0xc0007de080 CircuitBreakerConfig:{Enabled:true VolumeThreshold:0 ErrorThresholdPercentage:0 SleepWindow:0s RollingWindow:0s CompletionCallback:<nil> CanaryTimeout:0s} OrphanReporterConfig:{Enabled:true ReportInterval:0s SampleSize:0} TracerConfig:{Tracer:0xc0007de0a0 NoRootTraceSpans:true} MeterConfig:{Meter:<nil>}}
GOCB 12:48:01.777819 agent.go:75: HTTP muxer applying endpoints:
Bucket: 
Capi Eps:
Mgmt Eps:
  - http://localhost:8091
N1ql Eps:
FTS Eps:
CBAS Eps:
Eventing Eps:
GSI Eps:
Backup Eps:
GOCB 12:48:01.777877 agent.go:395: KV muxer applying endpoints:
Bucket: 
  - localhost:11210
GOCB 12:48:01.777959 agentgroup.go:40: HTTP muxer applying endpoints:
Bucket: 
Capi Eps:
Mgmt Eps:
  - http://localhost:8091
N1ql Eps:
FTS Eps:
CBAS Eps:
Eventing Eps:
GSI Eps:
Backup Eps:
GOCB 12:48:01.778006 ???:0: Pipeline Client `localhost:11210/0xc000046ba0` preparing for new client loop
GOCB 12:48:01.778030 ???:0: Pipeline Client `localhost:11210/0xc000046ba0` retrieving new client connection for parent 0xc000046ae0
GOCB 12:48:01.778038 asm_amd64.s:1594: CCCP Looper starting.
GOCB 12:48:01.778063 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:01.778074 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:01.778097 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:01.778092 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1ms, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:01.778117 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:01.778127 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:01.778139 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=10ms, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:01.778162 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:01.778172 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:01.778180 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:01.778180 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=50ms, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:01.778187 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=50ms, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:01.779163 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:01.779175 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:01.779183 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=500ms, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:01.780670 kvmux.go:669: Failed to connect. check server ports and cluster encryption setting: dial tcp [::1]:11210: connect: connection refused
GOCB 12:48:01.780722 ???:0: Pipeline Client 0xc000046ba0 failed to bootstrap: check server ports and cluster encryption setting: dial tcp [::1]:11210: connect: connection refused
GOCB 12:48:01.780731 ???:0: Pipeline Client `localhost:11210/0xc000046ba0` preparing for new client loop
GOCB 12:48:01.780738 ???:0: Pipeline Client `localhost:11210/0xc000046ba0` retrieving new client connection for parent 0xc000046ae0
GOCB 12:48:01.788226 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:01.788254 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:01.788267 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:01.828295 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:01.828340 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:01.828342 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:01.828354 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:01.828367 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:01.828361 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:02.280294 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:02.280338 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:02.280389 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:02.789178 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:02.789238 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:02.789262 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:02.828473 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:02.828522 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:02.828526 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:02.828594 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:02.828606 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:02.828547 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:03.281164 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:03.281210 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:03.281258 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:03.789944 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:03.789996 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:03.790017 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:03.829747 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:03.829804 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:03.829808 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:03.829826 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:03.829824 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:03.829837 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:04.281749 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:04.281800 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:04.281828 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:04.778775 cccpcfgcontroller.go:127: CCCPPOLL: Failed to retrieve CCCP config. check server ports and cluster encryption setting: dial tcp [::1]:11210: connect: connection refused
GOCB 12:48:04.778818 asm_amd64.s:1594: CCCPPOLL: Failed to retrieve config from any node.
GOCB 12:48:04.790206 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:04.790242 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:04.790258 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:04.829994 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:04.830080 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:04.830106 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:04.830145 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:04.830158 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:04.830147 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:05.282194 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:05.282223 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:05.282238 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:05.791413 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:05.791444 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:05.791460 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:05.830900 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:05.830966 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:05.830970 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:05.831020 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:05.830998 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:05.831032 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:06.282693 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:06.282740 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:06.282762 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:06.782541 kvmux.go:669: Failed to connect. check server ports and cluster encryption setting: dial tcp [::1]:11210: connect: connection refused
GOCB 12:48:06.782577 ???:0: Pipeline Client 0xc000046ba0 failed to bootstrap: check server ports and cluster encryption setting: dial tcp [::1]:11210: connect: connection refused
GOCB 12:48:06.782588 ???:0: Pipeline Client `localhost:11210/0xc000046ba0` preparing for new client loop
GOCB 12:48:06.782595 ???:0: Pipeline Client `localhost:11210/0xc000046ba0` retrieving new client connection for parent 0xc000046ae0
GOCB 12:48:06.791765 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:06.791794 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:06.791809 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:06.831121 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:06.831146 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:06.831152 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:06.831165 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:06.831174 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:06.831158 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:07.282931 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:07.283006 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:07.283029 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:07.792000 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:07.792025 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:07.792036 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:07.832089 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:07.832178 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:07.832232 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:07.832209 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:07.832279 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:07.832285 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:08.283162 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:08.283226 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:08.283241 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:08.792931 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:08.792958 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:08.792971 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:08.832345 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:08.832368 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:08.832383 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:08.832398 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:08.832410 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:08.832380 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:09.283369 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:09.283406 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:09.283421 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:09.793343 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:09.793400 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:09.793416 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:09.832487 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:09.832512 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:09.832525 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:09.832530 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:09.832546 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:09.832568 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:10.280417 cccpcfgcontroller.go:127: CCCPPOLL: Failed to retrieve CCCP config. check server ports and cluster encryption setting: dial tcp [::1]:11210: connect: connection refused
GOCB 12:48:10.280450 asm_amd64.s:1594: CCCPPOLL: Failed to retrieve config from any node.
GOCB 12:48:10.283890 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:10.283924 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:10.283945 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:10.793870 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:10.793896 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:10.793908 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:10.833456 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:10.833495 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:10.833506 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:10.833523 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:10.833571 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:10.833513 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:11.284143 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:11.284174 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:11.284188 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:11.783787 kvmux.go:669: Failed to connect. check server ports and cluster encryption setting: dial tcp [::1]:11210: connect: connection refused
GOCB 12:48:11.783820 ???:0: Pipeline Client 0xc000046ba0 failed to bootstrap: check server ports and cluster encryption setting: dial tcp [::1]:11210: connect: connection refused
GOCB 12:48:11.783827 ???:0: Pipeline Client `localhost:11210/0xc000046ba0` preparing for new client loop
GOCB 12:48:11.783832 ???:0: Pipeline Client `localhost:11210/0xc000046ba0` retrieving new client connection for parent 0xc000046ae0
GOCB 12:48:11.794279 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:11.794305 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:11.794317 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:11.833770 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:11.833849 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:11.833886 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:11.833854 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:11.833919 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:11.833930 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, 
OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:13.834278 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:13.834287 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:13.834301 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:13.834302 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:14.287363 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:14.287407 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:14.287457 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:14.797299 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:14.797347 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:14.797370 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:14.835393 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:14.835420 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:14.835437 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:14.835432 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:14.835455 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:14.835490 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:15.287666 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:15.287692 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:15.287702 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:15.781810 cccpcfgcontroller.go:127: CCCPPOLL: Failed to retrieve CCCP config. check server ports and cluster encryption setting: dial tcp [::1]:11210: connect: connection refused
GOCB 12:48:15.781867 asm_amd64.s:1594: CCCPPOLL: Failed to retrieve config from any node.
GOCB 12:48:15.798325 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:15.798357 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:15.798372 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:15.836102 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:15.836152 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:15.836166 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:15.836171 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:15.836200 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:15.836214 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:16.287891 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:16.287921 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:16.287937 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:16.785924 kvmux.go:669: Failed to connect. check server ports and cluster encryption setting: dial tcp [::1]:11210: connect: connection refused
GOCB 12:48:16.785976 ???:0: Pipeline Client 0xc000046ba0 failed to bootstrap: check server ports and cluster encryption setting: dial tcp [::1]:11210: connect: connection refused
GOCB 12:48:16.785991 ???:0: Pipeline Client `localhost:11210/0xc000046ba0` preparing for new client loop
GOCB 12:48:16.786002 ???:0: Pipeline Client `localhost:11210/0xc000046ba0` retrieving new client connection for parent 0xc000046ae0
GOCB 12:48:16.799515 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:16.799566 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:16.799587 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:16.837335 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:16.837393 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:16.837422 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:16.837457 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:16.837464 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:16.837415 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:17.288587 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:17.288644 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:17.288669 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:17.799838 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:17.799931 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:17.799954 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:17.838138 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:17.838206 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:17.838239 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:17.838311 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:17.838333 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:17.838265 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:18.289495 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:18.289540 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:18.289563 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:18.801005 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:18.801067 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:18.801108 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:18.838432 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:18.838491 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:18.838505 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:18.838524 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:18.838537 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:18.838537 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:19.290748 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:19.290799 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:19.290830 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:19.802278 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:19.802328 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:19.802352 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:19.838794 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:19.838820 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:19.838836 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:19.838852 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:19.838856 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:19.838863 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:20.291720 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:20.291771 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:20.291795 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:20.803461 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:20.803503 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:20.803573 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:20.838906 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:20.838943 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:20.838962 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:20.838991 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:20.838973 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:20.838998 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
GOCB 12:48:21.283735 cccpcfgcontroller.go:127: CCCPPOLL: Failed to retrieve CCCP config. check server ports and cluster encryption setting: dial tcp [::1]:11210: connect: connection refused
GOCB 12:48:21.283809 asm_amd64.s:1594: CCCPPOLL: Failed to retrieve config from any node.
GOCB 12:48:21.292879 ???:0: Bootstrap error found before config seen: <nil>
GOCB 12:48:21.292913 ???:0: No config seen yet in http muxer but no errors found.
GOCB 12:48:21.292932 asm_amd64.s:1594: Will retry request. Backoff=1s, OperationID=waituntilready. Reason=NOT_READY
unambiguous timeout | {"InnerError":{"InnerError":{"InnerError":{},"Message":"unambiguous timeout"}},"OperationID":"WaitUntilReady","Opaque":"","TimeObserved":20000021318,"RetryReasons":["NOT_READY"],"RetryAttempts":85,"LastDispatchedTo":"","LastDispatchedFrom":"","LastConnectionID":""}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, sorry, but I suggest you try SDK Doctor and see if it provides any useful output https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/sdk/sdk-doctor.html

Comment: You'll probable need to configure Alternate Addresses, so the Couchbase cluster knows the client is connecting to it via localhost. Relevant Couchbase blog post that specifically mentions port forwarding and AWS: https://www.couchbase.com/blog/alternate-address-por-support-for-couchbase-n1ql-clusters/

Comment: @MatthewGroves thank you for your reply Matthew. I tried it and it is very similiar with logs that I wrote above.

Comment: @dnault I dont think, it is allowed to expose alternate address due to security reasons. Is there any way to connect via localhost?

Comment: You don't need to expose more ports. Couchbase Alternate Addresses are for telling the client which addresses to use for connecting to the nodes and services in the cluster. In your case, the server must advertise alternate addresses that make it look like it's running locally. Instead of "Connect to the KV service at `com.example:11210`, you want the server to say "Connect to the KV service at `127.0.0.1:11210`" (the address of your tunnel).

Comment: See https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/clusters-and-availability/connectivity.html#alternate-addresses and https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/rest-api/rest-set-up-alternate-address.html